# Retain Information Entered Works in <input type="text" but not textarea

Tags: php, html, textarea

This is the PHP code I have:

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="materialize-textarea" value="<?php
if($form->value("name") == ""){
echo $session->userinfo['name'];
}else{
echo $form->value("name");
}
?>">
<?php echo $form->error("name"); ?>
```

When I fill in the text input and refresh the page, it keeps the content.

However I need to change it from a `<input type="text"` to a textarea - however when I do this, it does not keep the content.

Comment: You'll need to show *how* you tried to change it to a `<textarea>`. (The content belongs in tags there, not in a value= attribute).

Comment: Textarea doesn't have value, you should place your code between opening and closing textarea tag, i guess...

Comment: how have you tried changing it to textarea?

Comment: What framework are you using? Most likely it has a helper function like `-value()` that is for texareas